# Remove the "__c" from custom field API name

Tags: api, custom-object, custom-field

I've created a custom object in Salesforce with a number of custom fields. Is there any way to remove the "__c" from the API names of those custom fields?

Comment: You can not, it's standard behavior   `__c` differentiate the standard vs custom

Comment: why you want do remove __c. I think this could be a xy problem

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Custom fields always have the `__c` suffix and it is not optional.

Comment: and, moreover, the presence of the `__c` is how an admin/dev can easily tell if the field is custom v OOTB which leads to other insights